# How to resolve ipv6 ssh on Ubuntu 16.4 with possible interface ambiguity

Tags: ssh, ipv6, ubuntu-16.04

I have a new Ubuntu 16.04 install. I want to ssh into a MacBook Pro via IPV6.

I can ping the Mac from Ubuntu, but it requires me to specify -I.

```
$ ping6 -c 1 -I enp0s25 fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88
PING fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88(fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88) from fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e enp0s25: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.378 ms
```

versus

```
$ ping6 -c 1 fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88
connect: Invalid argument
```

My Ubuntu has only one adapter and interface.

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:77:91:fa 
...
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
...
```

I can ssh into the Mac from a Windows PC that uses PuTTY (plink). All three machines (MacBook, Windows, Ubuntu) are on the same network switch.

```
# bash on Windows
$ ssh test@fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88
Last login: Sat Nov 17 13:16:15 2018 from fe80::e119:5811:40e5:becf%en8
jws-mac:~ test$
```

On Ubuntu, this is the command I would like to work:

```
$ ssh -6 test@fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88
ssh: connect to host fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88 port 22: Invalid argument
```

It seems like it is a similar result to ping without -I switch. I don't want to use -b switch, because eventually I want to use git with IPV6 ssh url.

Pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a link-local IPv6 address, the **local** interface identifier must be specified with the **remote** address.

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:77:91:fa
...

$ ssh -6 test@fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88%enp0s25
```

or

**ssh -6 *user*@*remote-ipv6-address*%*local-interface-name***

Note `enp0s25` depends on the machine and is provided by ifconfig and plugged into ssh.

Here is an example of an ssh URL, for tools like git, assuming user `git` and subpath `repos/test.git`:

```
ssh://git@[fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88%25enp0s25]/repos/test.git
```

or

**ssh://*user*@[*remote-ipv6-address*%25*local-interface*]/*subpath***

Note the % that separates address from interface has to be URL-encoded as %25.